# jQuery AJAX - ¿como esperar a que terminen 2 peticiones AJAX antes de hacer un procesamiento con la respuesta de las 2?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

En esta ocasión les solicito una ayuda con respecto jQuery con un codigo que estoy creando que utiliza bootstrap, jquery, php, plug in TimeCircles (contador de tiempo regresivo utiliza bootstrap y jquery)

Hay una tabla donde cada fila son generadas dinámicamente por cada petición via AJAX con la función armarTablaDeHost(cantidadDeHost)

Inicialmente la tabla un mensaje de Cargando id="alertMensaje" aparecen invisibles.

En el codigo se hacen 2 peticiones AJAX utilizando $.getJSON()
La primera la hace desde una función javascript cantHost () que un script de PHP devuelve en formato JSON de la siguiente forma {"cantidad":"15"} dicho número representa la cantidad de datos que tiene que solicitar con otra petición AJAX una función llamada armarTablaDeHost(cantidadDeHost) cuyo parámetro es el numero de cantidad que se obtuvo de la primer función cantHost ()

armarTablaDeHost(cantidadDeHost) esta función tiene un ciclo for que itera del 1 a cantidadDeHost {"cantidad":"15"} en este caso de 1 a 15 que serían IDs, dentro del ciclo está la función getHostById(i) 
esta última función solicita vía AJAX datos sobre tal id, obtiene como resultado un JSON ejemplo {"id":"1","nombre":"Walter","estado":"Offline"} en la próxima petición del ciclo for {"id":"2","nombre":"Fernando","estado":"Online"} y así sucesivamente hasta llegar a cantidadDeHost {"cantidad":"15"} y va generando una fila en la tabla.

Una vez que haya terminado de armar la tabla debe iniciar la función iniciarContadorRegresivo() que es un contador de tiempo regresivo id="timer" y cuando este llegue a cero vuelve a iniciar nuevamente todo el ciclo desde el principio.

El problema está en que la petición AJAX getHostById(hostID) puede tardar tiempo en dar una respuesta y iniciarContadorRegresivo() inicia sin esperar que haya terminado getHostById(hostID) en generar todas las filas.

Aquí es donde estoy perdido.

En cantHost () utilizo $.when( armarTablaDeHost(cantidadDeHost)).then( iniciarContadorRegresivo());
donde intentó decirle a jQuery que inicie armarTablaDeHost(cantidadDeHost) y cuando haya terminado de generar todas las filas ejecute iniciarContadorRegresivo(), pero hace todo al mismo tiempo.

jQuery es más rápido que las respuesta AJAX del servidor.

Por lo que lei, entendi el concepto de que se trata pero no como se utiliza ni como lo hace que es posible hacerlo utilizando deferred.promise() de jQuery.

Aqui el codigo comentado y con los respectivos CDN de Bootstrap, jQuery, y plugin timecircles (contador de tiempo regresivo) para que puedan probarlo, claro está que no esta el codigo de php que devuelven las respuestas ya que no es necesario ya que este funcionando correctamente.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>AJAX</title>
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timecircles/1.5.3/TimeCircles.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timecircles/1.5.3/TimeCircles.min.css" />
    <style>
        .table tbody tr.success td {
            background-color: #dff0d8;
        }
        .table tbody tr.error td {
            background-color: #ef9a9a;
        }
        .table tbody tr.error td:hover {
            background-color: #ff8a80;
        }
        .table tbody tr.info td {
            background-color: #d9edf7;
        }
        .table tbody tr.warning td {
            background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
        }
        #timer, #tabla, #alertMensaje{
            display: none;
        }
        .badge-personalizado {
            background-color: white;
            color: #2d6987;
        }
        .badge-personalizado:hover {
            background-color: #004A7E;
            color: white;
        }
        .glyphicon-size{
            font-size: 1.5em !important;
        }
        .label-size{
            font-size: 1em !important;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        //contador regresivo
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $("#CountDownTimer").TimeCircles({count_past_zero: false, start: false, time: { Days: { show: false }, Hours: { show: false } }}).addListener(function(unit, value, total) {
                if(total <= 0) { // cuando el contador regresivo llega acero
                    $("#tabla").fadeOut('slow'); // esconde la tabla de datos
                    $("#CountDownTimer").TimeCircles().stop(); // detiene el contador
                    $("#timer").fadeOut('slow', function() {
                        $("#alertMensaje").fadeIn('slow'); //muestra el mensaje de Cargando
                        $("#tabla").find("tr:gt(0)").remove(); // elimina todos los tr de la tabla, filas con datos obtenidos previamente por AJAX
                        cantHost ();
                    });
                }
            });
            // cantidadDeHost=0;
            function cantHost (){
                // se obtien la cantidad de elementos con el cual se armara las filas de las tablas
                $("#tabla").fadeIn('slow'); // muestra la tabla de datos
                $("#alertMensaje").fadeIn('slow'); // muestra el mensaje de cargando
                $.getJSON( "test_ajax.php", {cantidad: "cantidad"},function( data ) {
                    $("#canidadDetHost").text( data.cantidad ); // imprimr la cantidad en el badge den el titulo
                    cantidadDeHost = data.cantidad; // cantidad de datos a ser peticionados
                    $.when(  armarTablaDeHost(cantidadDeHost)).then( iniciarContadorRegresivo());
                });
            }
            function armarTablaDeHost(cantidadDeHost){
                //Arma las filas de la tabla dinamicamente solicitando con AJAX los datos por ID
                for (i = 1; i <= cantidadDeHost; i++) {
                    getHostById(i);
                }
            }
            function getHostById(hostID) {
                // obtiene el dato por AJAX con el ID solicitado y genera la fila de la tabla
                $.getJSON( "test_ajax.php", {getHostById :hostID},function( data ) {
                    // agrega una fila a la tabla con el dato obteido por AJAX
                    $('#tabla > tbody:last').append('<tr id="filaID_'+ data.id+'"><td>'+ data.id +'- '+ data.nombre +'</td><td><span id="labelestado_'+ data.id+'" class="label label-size"></span></td><td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign text-info glyphicon-size"></span></td></tr>')
                    //Compara el estado para darle un estilo al label del estado
                    if(data.estado=='Online'){
                        // $('#filaID_'+ data.id).addClass('bg-success');
                        $('#labelestado_'+ data.id).addClass('label-success');
                        $('#labelestado_'+ data.id).html(data.estado+' <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span>');
                    }
                    if(data.estado=='Offline'){
                        $('#filaID_'+ data.id).addClass('error');
                        $('#labelestado_'+ data.id).addClass('label-danger')
                        $('#labelestado_'+ data.id).html(data.estado+' <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>');
                    }
                    if(data.estado=='No Existe'){
                        $('#filaID_'+ data.id).addClass('warning');
                        $('#labelestado_'+ data.id).addClass('label-warning');
                        $('#labelestado_'+ data.id).html(data.estado+' <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert"></span>');
                    }
                });
            }
            function iniciarContadorRegresivo(){
                $("#alertMensaje").fadeOut('slow', function() {
                    $("#timer").fadeIn('slow');
                    $("#CountDownTimer").TimeCircles().restart().end(); // incia el conteo
                })};
            cantHost(); // inicia al cargar la pagina por primera vez
        }); //jQuery
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="well well-sm text-primary"><h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Chequeo de estados Online de Hosts</h4></div>
    <div class="container" id="timer">
        <div class="center-block"id="CountDownTimer" data-timer="10" style="width: 200px"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-info" id="alertMensaje" role="alert"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></span> Chequeando...</div>
    <table id="tabla" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead class="bg-primary">
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-10"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;Host&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="badge badge-personalizado" id="canidadDetHost"></span></th>
            <th class="col-md-1">Estado</th>
            <th class="col-md-1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign glyphicon-size"></span></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div> <!-- container principal-->
</body>
</html>
```

test_ajax.php obtiene los datos de una base de datos y hace cierta comprobaciones las cuales pueden tardar en responder.

Para que puedan probarlo, hice un script emulandolo. La lista tiene los nombres de algunos usuarios de la comunidad.

Si el estado es Offline retengo el envío de la respuesta por algunos segundos, esto emula la tardanza en el tiempo de respuesta del servidor mediante la linea sleep(5); // espera 5 segundos
El codigo esta comentado con la explicación.

```
 <?php
// Colección de datos.
// El número representa al ID el cual tiene asociado un arreglo de datos son nombre y estado
// ej ID= 1 tiene: nombre: walter,  estado: Online
 $lista = array(
        1 =>
         array(
             'nombre'=>'Walter',
             'estado'=>'Online'
         ),
         2 =>array(
             'nombre'=>'Fernando',
             'estado'=>'Online'
         ),
         3 =>array(
             'nombre'=>'Carlos',
             'estado'=>'Offline'
         ),
         4 =>array(
             'nombre'=>'Ernesto',
             'estado'=>'Online'
         ),
         5 =>array(
             'nombre'=>'Ernesto',
             'estado'=>'Offline'
         ),
         6 =>array(
             'nombre'=>'Txema',
             'estado'=>'Online'
         ),
         7 =>array(
             'nombre'=>'Antuan',
             'estado'=>'Online'
         ),
         8 =>array(
             'nombre'=>'Juan',
             'estado'=>'Offline'
         ),
         9 =>array(
             'nombre'=>'CorpLan',
             'estado'=>'Offline'
         ),
         10 =>array(
             'nombre'=>'Chrismart',
             'estado'=>'Online'
         ),
         11 =>array(
             'nombre'=>'Gustavo',
             'estado'=>'Online'
         ),
         12 =>array(
             'nombre'=>'Karen',
             'estado'=>'Online'
         ),
         13 =>array(
             'nombre'=>'Gonzalo',
             'estado'=>'Online'
         ),
         14 =>array(
             'nombre'=>'Edwin',
             'estado'=>'Online'
         ),
         15 =>array(
             'nombre'=>'Bryan',
             'estado'=>'Offline'
         ),
                );
 if(isset($_GET)){ // Si esta definido GET
    if(isset($_GET["cantidad"])){ // Si solicita la cantidad de elementos de la lista
        echo get_cantidad($lista);
    }
    if(isset($_GET["getHostById"])){ // si solicita datos de un elemento de la lista por medio del ID
        echo  $datos=get_datosById($_GET["getHostById"],$lista);
    }
}
// Funcion que devuelve los datos sobre un ID
function get_datosById($id=0,$arrayDatos){
    $rta = array("id"=>0,"nombre"=>'',"estado"=>''); // respuesta por defecto si el ID no existe
    if($id>0){
        if ( array_key_exists($id, $arrayDatos))
        {
            // El ID se encontrado en la lista, devuelve los datos asociados al ID
            $rta = array("id"=>$id,"nombre"=>$arrayDatos [$id]['nombre'],"estado"=>$arrayDatos [$id]['estado']);
            // si el estado es Offline retengo el envio de la respuesta por algunos segundos
            if ($arrayDatos [$id]['estado']=='Offline'){
                sleep(5); // espera 5 segundos
            }
        }
    }
    return json_encode($rta);
}
// Funcion que devuelve la cantidad de datos de la lista
function get_cantidad($arrayDatos){
    $rta = array("cantidad"=>count($arrayDatos)); //  devuelve la cantidad de elementos del Array de la Lista
    return json_encode($rta);
}
```

¿como esperar a que terminen 2 peticiones AJAX antes de hacer un procesamiento con la respuesta de las 2?
Walter · hace 6 horas

Hola

He estado preacticando y me hice una appweb intentado aplicar lo aprendido a lo largo de este curso.

En esta ocasión les solicito una ayuda con respecto jQuery con un codigo que estoy creando que utiliza bootstrap, jquery, php, plug in TimeCircles (contador de tiempo regresivo utiliza bootstrap y jquery)

Paso a explicar.

Hay una tabla donde cada fila son generadas dinámicamente por cada petición via AJAX con la función

armarTablaDeHost(cantidadDeHost)

Inicialmente la tabla un mensaje de Cargando id="alertMensaje" aparecen invisibles.

En el codigo se hacen 2 peticiones AJAX utilizando $.getJSON()
La primera la hace desde una función javascript cantHost () que un script de PHP devuelve en formato JSON de la siguiente forma {"cantidad":"15"} dicho número representa la cantidad de datos que tiene que solicitar con otra petición AJAX una función llamada armarTablaDeHost(cantidadDeHost) cuyo parámetro es el numero de cantidad que se obtuvo de la primer función cantHost ()

armarTablaDeHost(cantidadDeHost) esta función tiene un ciclo for que itera del 1 a cantidadDeHost{"cantidad":"15"} en este caso de 1 a 15 que serían IDs, dentro del ciclo está la función getHostById(i) 
esta última función solicita vía AJAX datos sobre tal id, obtiene como resultado un JSON ejemplo {"id":"1","nombre":"Walter","estado":"Offline"} en la próxima petición del ciclo for {"id":"2","nombre":"Fernando","estado":"Online"} y así sucesivamente hasta llegar a cantidadDeHost{"cantidad":"15"} y va generando una fila en la tabla.

Una vez que haya terminado de armar la tabla debe iniciar la función iniciarContadorRegresivo() que es un contador de tiempo regresivo id="timer" y cuando este llegue a cero vuelve a iniciar nuevamente todo el ciclo desde el principio.

El problema está en que la petición AJAX getHostById(hostID) puede tardar tiempo en dar una respuesta y iniciarContadorRegresivo() inicia sin esperar que haya terminado getHostById(hostID) en generar todas las filas.

Aquí es donde estoy perdido.

En cantHost () utilizo $.when( armarTablaDeHost(cantidadDeHost)).then( iniciarContadorRegresivo());
donde intentó decirle a jQuery que inicie armarTablaDeHost(cantidadDeHost) y cuando haya terminado de generar todas las filas ejecute iniciarContadorRegresivo(), pero hace todo al mismo tiempo.

jQuery es más rápido que las respuesta AJAX del servidor.

Aqui el código comentado y con los respectivos CDN de Bootstrap, jQuery, y plugin timecircles (contador de tiempo regresivo) para que puedan probarlo, claro está que no esta el código de php que devuelven las respuestas ya que no es necesario ya que este funcionando correctamente.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>AJAX</title>
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timecircles/1.5.3/TimeCircles.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timecircles/1.5.3/TimeCircles.min.css" />
    <style>
        .table tbody tr.success td {
            background-color: #dff0d8;
        }
        .table tbody tr.error td {
            background-color: #ef9a9a;
        }
        .table tbody tr.error td:hover {
            background-color: #ff8a80;
        }
        .table tbody tr.info td {
            background-color: #d9edf7;
        }
        .table tbody tr.warning td {
            background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
        }

        #timer, #tabla, #alertMensaje{
            display: none;
        }
        .badge-personalizado {
            background-color: white;
            color: #2d6987;
        }
        .badge-personalizado:hover {
            background-color: #004A7E;
            color: white;
        }
        .glyphicon-size{
            font-size: 1.5em !important;
        }
        .label-size{
            font-size: 1em !important;
        }
    </style>

    <script>

        //contador regresivo
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $("#CountDownTimer").TimeCircles({count_past_zero: false, start: false, time: { Days: { show: false }, Hours: { show: false } }}).addListener(function(unit, value, total) {
                if(total <= 0) { // cuando el contador regresivo llega a cero
                    $("#tabla").fadeOut('slow'); // esconde la tabla de datos
                    $("#CountDownTimer").TimeCircles().stop(); // detiene el contador
                    $("#timer").fadeOut('slow', function() {
                        $("#alertMensaje").fadeIn('slow'); //muestra el mensaje de Cargando
                        $("#tabla").find("tr:gt(0)").remove(); // elimina todos los tr de la tabla, filas con datos obtenidos previamente por AJAX
                        cantHost ();
                    });
                }
            });
            // cantidadDeHost=0;
            function cantHost (){

                // se obtien la cantidad de elementos con el cual se armara las filas de las tablas
                $("#tabla").fadeIn('slow'); // muestra la tabla de datos
                $("#alertMensaje").fadeIn('slow'); // muestra el mensaje de cargando
                $.getJSON( "test_ajax.php", {cantidad: "cantidad"},function( data ) {
                    $("#canidadDetHost").text( data.cantidad ); // imprimir la cantidad en el badge en el titulo
                    cantidadDeHost = data.cantidad; // cantidad de datos a ser peticionados
                    $.when(  armarTablaDeHost(cantidadDeHost)).then( iniciarContadorRegresivo());
                });
            }


            function armarTablaDeHost(cantidadDeHost){
                //Arma las filas de la tabla dinamicamente solicitando con AJAX los datos por ID
                for (i = 1; i <= cantidadDeHost; i++) {
                    getHostById(i);
                }
            }

            function getHostById(hostID) {
                // obtiene el dato por AJAX con el ID solicitado y genera la fila de la tabla
                $.getJSON( "test_ajax.php", {getHostById :hostID},function( data ) {
                    // agrega una fila a la tabla con el dato obteido por AJAX
                    $('#tabla > tbody:last').append('<tr id="filaID_'+ data.id+'"><td>'+ data.id +'- '+ data.nombre +'</td><td><span id="labelestado_'+ data.id+'" class="label label-size"></span></td><td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign text-info glyphicon-size"></span></td></tr>')
                    //Compara el estado para darle un estilo al label del estado
                    if(data.estado=='Online'){
                        // $('#filaID_'+ data.id).addClass('bg-success');
                        $('#labelestado_'+ data.id).addClass('label-success');
                        $('#labelestado_'+ data.id).html(data.estado+' <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span>');
                    }

                    if(data.estado=='Offline'){
                        $('#filaID_'+ data.id).addClass('error');
                        $('#labelestado_'+ data.id).addClass('label-danger')
                        $('#labelestado_'+ data.id).html(data.estado+' <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>');
                    }

                    if(data.estado=='No Existe'){
                        $('#filaID_'+ data.id).addClass('warning');
                        $('#labelestado_'+ data.id).addClass('label-warning');
                        $('#labelestado_'+ data.id).html(data.estado+' <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert"></span>');
                    }

                });
            }


            function iniciarContadorRegresivo(){

                $("#alertMensaje").fadeOut('slow', function() {
                    $("#timer").fadeIn('slow');
                    $("#CountDownTimer").TimeCircles().restart().end(); // incia el conteo

                })};

            cantHost(); // inicia al cargar la pagina por primera vez

        }); //jQuery
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="well well-sm text-primary"><h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link" aria-hidden="true"></span>  Chequeo de estados Online de Hosts</h4></div>
    <div class="container" id="timer">

        <div class="center-block"id="CountDownTimer" data-timer="10" style="width: 200px"></div>

    </div>

    <div class="alert alert-info" id="alertMensaje" role="alert"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></span> Chequeando...</div>


    <table id="tabla" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead class="bg-primary">
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-10"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload" aria-hidden="true"></span> Host  <span class="badge badge-personalizado" id="canidadDetHost"></span></th>
            <th class="col-md-1">Estado</th>
            <th class="col-md-1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign glyphicon-size"></span></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>

</div> <!-- container principal-->
</body>
</html>
```

test_ajax.php obtiene los datos de una base de datos y hace cierta comprobaciones las cuales pueden tardar en responder.

Para que puedan probarlo, hice un script emulandolo. La lista tiene nombres y estado.

Si el estado es Offline retengo el envío de la respuesta por algunos segundos, esto emula la tardanza en el tiempo de respuesta del servidor mediante la linea sleep(5); // espera 5 segundos
El codigo esta comentado con la explicación.

test_ajax.php

```
<?php
// Colección de datos.
// El número representa al ID el cual tiene asociado un arreglo de datos son nombre y estado
// ej ID= 1 tiene: nombre: walter,  estado: Online
 $lista = array(
        1 =>
         array(
             'nombre'=>'Walter',
             'estado'=>'Online'
         ),
         2 =>array(
             'nombre'=>'Fernando',
             'estado'=>'Online'
         ),
         3 =>array(
             'nombre'=>'Carlos',
             'estado'=>'Offline'
         ),
         4 =>array(
             'nombre'=>'Ernesto',
             'estado'=>'Online'
         ),
         5 =>array(
             'nombre'=>'Ernesto',
             'estado'=>'Offline'
         ),
         6 =>array(
             'nombre'=>'Txema',
             'estado'=>'Online'
         ),
         7 =>array(
             'nombre'=>'Antuan',
             'estado'=>'Online'
         ),
         8 =>array(
             'nombre'=>'Juan',
             'estado'=>'Offline'
         ),
         9 =>array(
             'nombre'=>'CorpLan',
             'estado'=>'Offline'
         ),
         10 =>array(
             'nombre'=>'Chrismart',
             'estado'=>'Online'
         ),
         11 =>array(
             'nombre'=>'Gustavo',
             'estado'=>'Online'
         ),
         12 =>array(
             'nombre'=>'Karen',
             'estado'=>'Online'
         ),
         13 =>array(
             'nombre'=>'Gonzalo',
             'estado'=>'Online'
         ),
         14 =>array(
             'nombre'=>'Edwin',
             'estado'=>'Online'
         ),
         15 =>array(
             'nombre'=>'Bryan',
             'estado'=>'Offline'
         ),
                );

 if(isset($_GET)){ // Si esta definido GET
    if(isset($_GET["cantidad"])){ // Si solicita la cantidad de elementos de la lista
        echo get_cantidad($lista);
    }
    if(isset($_GET["getHostById"])){ // si solicita datos de un elemento de la lista por medio del ID
        echo  $datos=get_datosById($_GET["getHostById"],$lista);
    }
}

// Funcion que devuelve los datos sobre un ID
function get_datosById($id=0,$arrayDatos){
    $rta = array("id"=>0,"nombre"=>'',"estado"=>''); // respuesta por defecto si el ID no existe
    if($id>0){
        if ( array_key_exists($id, $arrayDatos))
        {
            // El ID se encontrado en la lista, devuelve los datos asociados al ID
            $rta = array("id"=>$id,"nombre"=>$arrayDatos [$id]['nombre'],"estado"=>$arrayDatos [$id]['estado']);
            // si el estado es Offline retengo el envio de la respuesta por algunos segundos
            if ($arrayDatos [$id]['estado']=='Offline'){
                sleep(5); // espera 5 segundos
            }
        }
    }
    return json_encode($rta);
}

// Funcion que devuelve la cantidad de datos de la lista
function get_cantidad($arrayDatos){
    $rta = array("cantidad"=>count($arrayDatos)); //  devuelve la cantidad de elementos del Array de la Lista
    return json_encode($rta);
}
```

Explicando un poco la respuesta del servidor, el codigo test_ajax.php

La solicitud por GET: ajax.php?cantidad devuelve como respuesta: {"cantidad":15}

La solicitud por GET: ajax.php?getHostById=1 devuelve como respuesta: {"id":"1","nombre":"Walter","estado":"Online"}

La solicitud por GET: ajax.php?getHostById=1 devuelve como respuesta: {"id":"3","nombre":"Carlos","estado":"Offline"}
Por ejemplo la última solicitud tardaria mas en responder.​

El resultado se vería algo como lo siguiente:

[image: Captura de pantalla]

Como se puede ver en la captura de pantalla anterior, sucede lo siguiente
Aparece el

```
Chequeando...
```

El cual deberia ocultarse cuando se haya mostrado todas las filas de las tablas.

El contador regresivo de tiempo deberia aparecer y comenzar en 10 cuando se haya ocultado el DIV anterior o bien se haya mostrado todas las filas de las tablas.

Cuando el contador llegue a 0 comenzar todo elciclo nuevamnete con las peticiones de AJAX

Espero que me haya sido explicado bien ya que es un poco complicado hacerlo por las funcionalidades del codigo.

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Que tengan un buen dia.

Saludos :)

Answer (score 1):

Hola en efecto es con un deferred la info aquí

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

La verdad es que tu pregunta es muy amplia y el código es demasiado, no pude ni Leerlo, por lo que yo resumiría la pregunta a:

**¿como esperar a que terminen 2 peticiones AJAX antes de hacer un procesamiento con la respuesta de las 2?**

Y lo que tienes que hacer es que en el `$.when()` metes, en separación con comas cada una de las peticiones;

```
$.when($.getJSON( "test_ajax.php"), $.getJSON("otro_ajax.php")
.done(function(textAjaxResult, otroAjaxResult){
   // Se hace algo con textAjaxResult y otroAjaxResult
})
.fail(function(error){ //siempre pon el fail, en caso de que algo falle
  console.error("OCURRIO UN ERROR: ", error);
});
```

Al resolverse las 2, entrará al `.done()` ahi es cuando debes hacer el array que armas y todo eso.

Por favor trata de hacerlo y si te da problemas, te hacemos un videotutorial, solo comentalo y mencionalo en tu comentario para poder recibir el mail.

Saludos